# Show how a sentence can be produced from a grammar (Dragon book 2.1)

Tags: formal-grammars, context-free

In the Dragon book (Aho, Sethi, Ullmann) there is one exercise I don't get.

> Chapter 2, Exercies: 2.1
>   Given the context-free grammar
>   $$S \to S S + \mid S S * \mid a$$
>   Task: Show how the signs aa+a* can be produced from this grammar.

I understand the grammar, $S$ can have the form $S S +$… and so on. But I don't know what I'm supposed to do in this task. Sadly I can't find any solutions on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
S \Rightarrow & SS* \\
  \Rightarrow & SS+S* & \text{(leftmost derivation )} \\
  \Rightarrow & aS+S* \\
  \Rightarrow & aa+S* \\
  \Rightarrow & aa+a* \\
\end{align*}$$